# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, api, flask

I am trying to run a service even when API link is down but I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'.
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you

```
 *@app.route('/test_api')
    def test_api():
        ipno = "192.168.0.120"
        port = "8060"

        url_time = 'https://{}:{}/time/'.format(ipno, port)
        url_member = 'https://{}:{}/member/'.format(ipno, port)
        url_state = 'https://{}:{}/state/'.format(ipno, port)

        try:
            r_time = _session.get(url_time).content

            r_member = _session.get(url_member).content

            r_state = _session.get(url_state).content
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            r_uptime = {
                        "uptime": "OFF"
                        }.decode(utf-8)
            r_member ={
                        "groupCount": "OFF",
                      }.decode(utf-8)
            r_state={   "state": "OFF"
                    }.decode(utf-8)


        return render_template('test_api.html', time = json.loads(r_time), member=json.loads(r_member), state=json.loads(r_state))*
```

Comment: decode is a string method and only works on strings, not dicts. Although there are a bunch of other issues here..

Comment: You might wanna jsonify your dict before you apply decode, but that entirely depends on what you're trying to do. In my opinion, you should remove the decode part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to have lots of errors.

First, you are using different names for same variable: `r_time` and `r_uptime`

Second, you are using different types for `r_xxx` values: strings in `try` and `dict` in `except` clause. I think, following code will better suite your needs:

```
import json.decoder
...
try:
    r_uptime = json.loads(_session.get(url_time).content)
    r_member = json.loads(_session.get(url_member).content)
    r_state = json.loads(_session.get(url_state).content)
except (json.decoder.JSONDecodeError, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) as ex:
    r_uptime = {"uptime": "OFF"}
    r_member = {"groupCount": "OFF"}
    r_state = {"state": "OFF"}
return render_template('test_api.html', time = r_uptime, member=r_member, state=r_state)
```